# What is latest version available for AWS cloudsearch access policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudsearch

HI currently available version for AWS cloudsearch access policy is very old = "2012-10-17" is there any new version available right now?

Comment: What do you mean "it's old"? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no newer version of the policy language for IAM policies in AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html

The versions that are available are:

```
2012-10-17
2008-10-17
```